# Searching  in Stack Overflow, all the questions which contain the word "apple", but not tagged as [apple]

Tags: discussion, support, search

I am using the search option of the Stack Overflow, but I can't figure out how search all the questions with contains the "apple" word but not tagged as [apple]. I just read the help about [searches](https://stackoverflow.com/search), but I did not find anything similar.

Is it possible make this search?

**UPDATE**

I found the way, to make this search the word must be enclosed in quotes

`"apple" -[apple]`

Comment: Your update is an _answer_ to the question; it would be best to post it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would search like this

`apple [-apple]`

which will search for the term apple but not tagged as apple

Sorry I have given you how to search for tags but excluding a tag. e.g Search for questions tagged with `asp` but not tagged `asp.net`

`[asp] -[asp.net]`

It would appear that the not operator `-` can only be used for tag searches not combined word and tag searches.